# How does this CSS work

Tags: css

[This web page](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/home/) uses a vertical menu that shows a neat little arrow pointing from the currently selected menu item to the page.  I examined the code in Chrome and found the following.

1. For the anchor that displays the arrow the markup is

   <li class="current">
   <a...>
   ::before
   "Welcome"
   </a>

The corresponding CSS is

```
aside li.current a:before
{
 content:"";
 border-color:transparent transparent transparent #fff;
 border-style:solid;
 border-width:10px;
 width:0;height:0;position:absolute;left:-30px;
}
```

I have a fair idea of what is going on here but I haven't quite been able to figure out just how it is that the end result is a triangle pointing to the left.  Perhaps someone who understands CSS better than I might be able to explain?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=css+triangle

Comment: Nice!  Thanks.  It never occurred to me to Google for CSS + Triangle but your comment prompted me to try [CSS Shapes](http://www.css3shapes.com). Hopefully, it will help others running into this thread.

Answer (score 0):

you had used border color of top right and bottom transparent and so it will take color of your left main div. Also as you had used a:before so before start of every a tag it will create this kind of structure in which no content is there and with position absolute you can set it as a triangle view...

If you remove transparent from your code and give colors to border you can see that originally its just like simple square box. So, its a CSS tips and tricks to make shapes using CSS.